# Xcode library reverted to 5.1 from 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have been developing an app using `Xcode`, which included the `Facebook SDK`. The `Facebook SDK` requires the `AdSupport.framework` and the `Social.framework`, both of which were previously installed, but seem to have disappeared. My question is how do it update the library to 6.0, instead of five? I understand that you have to go into the build phases and add the frameworks in the `Line Binary With Libraries` section, but when I go to add the framework, the folder is 5.1, not six. I have looked through the Apple doc's and haven't found anything.

Here is an image of what I'm getting:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: It happened to me but is possibly a dumb question regardless: is there any chance you've inadvertently kept an old install of Xcode (eg, in /Developer from before Xcode became an all-in-one bundle) and launched that instead of the latest version (eg, by typing 'xcode' into Searchlight and hitting enter without paying too much attention)?

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Make that an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no way the SDKs provided with Xcode can regress. However you could see them vanish if you launch an older version of Xcode.

Based on experience, if you had Xcode installed before it was a single app bundle and have subsequently installed the app bundle version then there's a reasonable probability the old version is still present and therefore good odds that a Spotlight launch will open the wrong one.